# How to show path a curl request takes?

Tags: curl, traceroute

I have a setup where request go from servers `x->y->z` where `y` can be seen as a reverse proxy. When I make a `curl` to y, I want to be able to see the request go from x to y to z. This is something similar to what `traceroute` would do.

How can I should the ip addresses that my requests bounces to on its way to the final destination?

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do it from client side. When proxying the request there are two separate connections: One between you and the proxy and another between the proxy and the backend. You need access to the proxy and/or backend server to read its log files to figure it out.

If the server is doing redirects instead of proxying, you can see the redirection path by using `curl -Li` which follows redirections and shows all response headers.